# How do I import and use a python module that imports classes from another file within itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am an experienced C# developer but have recently had to write some python code. I really like the language but I'm struggling with splitting some of my code into modules. For simplicity, I have essentially 2 modules with the first looking like this:

*file1.py*

```
from file2 import addOperation, volumeOperation

class utils:

  def add(self, num1, num2):
    op = addOperation(num1, num2)
    return op.calculate()

  def volume(self, length, width, height):
    op = volumeOperation(length, width, height)
    return op.calculate()

def main():
  util = utils()
  print(f"Adding 2 and 3 produces { util.add(2, 3) }")
  print(f"Volume of a 2x2x2 cube is { util.volume(2,2,2) }")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

*file2.py*

```
class addOperation:
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2

    def calculate(self):
        return self.num1 + self.num2

class volumeOperation:
    def __init__(self, length, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.length = length

    def calculate(self):
        return self.width * self.height * self.length
```

*_init__.py*

```
import file1, file2
```

Those 3 files sit in a folder called "mylibrary" and when I run "python .\file1.py" everything works as expected. The module then gets built into a wheel using this setup.py:

```
import setuptools

print(setuptools.find_packages())

setuptools.setup(
    name="mylibrary",
    version="1.0.0",
    author="me",
    author_email="me@me.com",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent"
    ],
)
```

The resulting wheel then gets installed using "python -m pip install --user mylibrary-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl" which appears to work just fine.

My second module is the following file "consumer.py":

```
import mylibrary.file1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    util = mylibrary.file1.utils()
    print(f"Adding 2 and 3 produces { util.add(2, 3) }")
    print(f"Volume of a 2x2x2 cube is { util.volume(2,2,2) }")
```

When I try  to run "python .\consumer.py" (I'm on windows using python 3.7, btw) I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file2'".

I have tried different ways of importing, I've tried using an empty `__init__.py` in the mylibrary module, and I have read a few other stackoverflow questions that at least have similar problems but I haven't been able to get it to work.

**What should I modify for this to work?**

Comment: Have you verified that `file2` is in the pip module directory as expected?

Comment: It seems that `file2` is within `mylibrary` and that you should be importing it as `import mylibrary.file2`, rather than just `import file2`

Comment: @Eqomatic It is indeed there.

Comment: @zvone That "__init__.py" file is in the mylibrary folder and gets included with the wheel. I did update it to be "import mylibrary.file1, mylibrary.file2" but that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: @Tom that was one half of the required change (which I missed in the first version of my answer), the other one is that the implicit relative import in `file1.py` also needs fixing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3, **implicit** relative imports [got removed](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax):

> The only acceptable syntax for relative imports is from .[module] import name. All import forms not starting with . are interpreted as absolute imports. ([PEP 0328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328))

Your

```
from file2 import ...
```

in *file1.py* is such an implicit relative import (i.e., it would have worked as a relative import in Python 2, but is now treated as an absolute import in Python 3).

---

So, you'll need to change it to either an absolute import:

```
from mylibrary.file2 import ...
```

or an **explicit** relative import (using a leading dot):

```
from .file2 import ...
```

If you really do need them, you'll also need to convert the imports in your `__init__.py` to

```
from . import file1
from . import file2
```

Other than that, your setuptools distribution seems to be layed out properly, and works for me (nice minimal example BTW!).

Comment: This seems to have worked on my sample code. I am trying to make similar changes to my real code and get a build running to see if this completely solves my problem before answering. About to head home for the weekend though so if this doesn't work on my first try I won't be able to revisit until Monday. (This project's real code is on a completely isolated network :( )

Comment: I'm back in business! Thanks for your help and clear explanation.

Comment: @Tom Great, thanks for letting me know. Also, feel free to ping me if you run into packaging trouble outside the scope of this question, happy to help if I can ;)